# Can't build a gtkmm4 application under win86

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, vcpkg

I installed gtkmm 4 via vcpkg.

And I'm trying to build test applications from [here](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en).

Under x64, the build and launch are successful.

Under x86, there are problems in the source file gdataset.c

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDTsE.png)

I use:

- C++ 17 Standard
- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.11.23

If you need more information, please, write comments

Comment: It looks like your datalist is corrupt. Now you have to find out where in your program this happened.